# Centering a SELECT in iOS Safari

Tags: html, ios, css, safari, centering

I'm trying to center a `SELECT` inside a `DIV` using the following code:

HTML:

```
<div class="myform">
  <form action="http://www.domain.com/" method="post">
  <select>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
  </select>
  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.myform select {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

It works correctly on desktop browsers, but on iOS Safari the drop-down menu is left aligned instead.

My question is, does Safari ignore any styling on `SELECT` tags?

Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/s87Ew/

Comment: Maybe a full fiddle or the page would be nice. :)

Comment: Have you set width for div.myform?

Comment: Fiddle added: http://jsfiddle.net/s87Ew/